# Configuring Sonarqube analysis in CI build in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to run sonarqube analysis on code commit itself .
I have added 1) prepare analysis configuration and 2) run code analysis, tasks in CI build.
But I am getting an error :
" No agent found in pool mypool which satisfies the specified demands: msbuild visualstudio java
Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1"

Can anyone please guide on what the issue is ?
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: Private agents running as services on separate build server . We have created separate build agents.

Comment: In the build server there is are visual studio and java installed?

Comment: I am not sure on that I'll have to check, it can be a jdk issue. Do I need to install sonar scanner too ,on the build server?

Comment: Shayki, can this be related to msbuild versions available under program files (86) . I have 12 and 15 available under msbuild but 15 doesn't have bin folder . Earlier I faced this issue while running scanner locally on pc , it required version 14 n above.

Comment: So try to install 15 and check again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Configuring Sonarqube analysis in CI build in VSTS

According to the error message:

> error : " No agent found in pool mypool which satisfies the specified
>   demands: msbuild visualstudio java Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1"

Which means that your private agent does not meet all the demands you set, including `msbuild`, `visualstudio`, `java`, `Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1`.

So, you should double check if your private agent has those demands, you could move those demands one by one, to check which one is not up to the requirements.

AFAIK, to configure Sonarqube analysis in CI build in Azure Devops, we need following demands:

- Make sure the .NET Framework v4.6+ is installed
- Make sure the Java Runtime Environment 8 is installed
- Install the extension [SonarQube](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) from the marketplace

Check the document Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS-TFS for some details.

Hope this helps.